# How to bulk update related records in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x, update-all

Can somebody help me with the correct approach on updating multiple records related to a table and based on a condition.

I am trying to update the field `is_deleted` for all comments in comment table, if the comment is related to a deleted post.

Below is the code I tried.

```
$commentsTable->query()
->join([
    'table' => 'Posts',
    'type' => 'inner',
    'conditions'=>  ['Posts.id = Comments.post_id', 'Posts.is_deleted = 1'],
])->updateAll(['Comments.is_deleted' => 1],[]);
```

I can use simple query to do this, but want to know how to handle this using Cakephp Query Builder.

Comment: Is the field in `Posts` called `is_delete` or `is_deleted`?

Comment: updateAll function needs 2 parameters Cake\ORM\Table::updateAll($fields, $conditions)

Comment: Sorry @GregSchmidt - that was a typo. It is **is_deleted**

Comment: Then in addition to what @Sehdev said, you might need to disambiguate with `'Comments.is_deleted' => 1` in your `updateAll` call.

Comment: I tried to add condition to `updateAll`, but doesn't help. I also changed it to `Comments.is_deleted` but isn't helping